# Excel, sum cells but ignore text. Cells are referenced from another sheet and concatenated

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I know similar questions have been asked, but I've been Googling for a few days now and haven't found a solution that actually works for me.  I will try to make this as clear and short as possible, let me know if you need more clarification.

For simplicity's sake, I want to sum two cells on Sheet1, `=sum(H26:H27)`, they read as **BillA $ 5.05** and **BillB $ 8.07**.  The values in those cells are actually referenced from Sheet2. Cell H26 is `=Sheet2!BG42`, Cell H27 is `=Sheet2!BH37` Here is where it gets interesting. . .

On Sheet2, Cell BG42 is `=C18&" "&TEXT(ROUNDUP(E18/3,2), "$ #,##0.00")`
and Cell BH37 is `=C8&" "&TEXT(ROUNDUP(E8/4,2), "$ #,##0.00")`

I use the formulas for cells `BG42` and `BH37` to make them concatenate cells `C18` and `E18`, but also divide E18 by a variable (1-6), and format them in a $ 9.99 format. Same for cells `C8` and `E8`.

Cells `C18` and `C8` are always only text, and cells `E18` and `E8` are always only number values (with Accounting Format).

So for example, if the values for `E18` and `E8` are 15.15 and 32.28 respectively, the final outcome should be **$ 13.12**

Currently, when I attempt `=SUM(H26:H27)` the output i get is **$     -**

Thank you in advance!

-Greg

Answer (score 0):

So, do the sum using the values you have in Sheet2 based on E18 including the division by the variable you mention.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you.  Do you mean `=SUM(SHEET2!BG42,SHEET2!BH37)`?  Summing the value's directly from sheet 2, rather than the cells that reference sheet 2?  After trying that I am still getting the result **$     -**

Comment: Sum the source data i.e. E8 and E18 according to your question - they should sum no problem - unless you have a custom format...

Comment: So this was a very stipped down version of an example.  In my full spreadsheet I have way more than two cells to reference.  I have over 200 cells that I may reference from.  But at any given time I'm only SUMing 2-6 values at a time.  So I can't just SUM the original cells that I've concatenated, added text to, divided, and rounded up to a value. I need to sum cells on SHEET2, but those cells are referenced on SHEET1, and those cells have been conatenated, had text added to them, divided by a viriable, and rounded up.

Comment: Then I can only suggest that you use MID() to get the numeric values you need, make sure that they are converted to values using VALUE() and complete from there. I still think that going to the original source values will be easier...